# Fill first available column based on a string in R

Tags: r, subset

Happy Monday -

I've used grep to create df2, subsetting df1 to return only those rows with a specific string.

What I'm after is a way to fill only the first available column (from A, B or C) with the value from the string (in this case 3).

```
df2 <- df1[grep("DW 3*", df1$D), ]
```

df2:

```
ID A B C D
1  3 3   DW 3*
2  4     DW 3*
3  4 3   DW 3*
4  3     DW 3*
```

So I end up with

```
ID A B C  D
 1  3 3 3  DW 3*
 2  4 3    DW 3*
 3  4 3 3  DW 3*
 4  3 3    DW 3*
```

I hope that is clear - feel free to ask for clarification, and thanks in advance.

Comment: "First available value" - is it `NA` or `""`?

Comment: Good point - currently NA, I can change that if easier though..

Comment: `data.frame(t(apply(df2, 1, function(x) {x[which(is.na(x))[1]] <- 3; x})))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate using apply to find first `NA` value and replace it with `3`

```
data.frame(t(apply(df2, 1, 
                   function(x) {x[which(is.na(x))[1]] <- 3; x})))
```

Comment: Great - this worked a treat - went for apply over the for loop solution out of habit, but thanks to all!

Comment: @C_psy Happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop to find the first `NA` value and then replace it with the value you require:

(I couldn't work out where you're getting your value from, so I just hard coded `3` as the replacement value)

Set up data:

```
df2 = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4),A=c(3,4,4,3), B=c(3,NA,NA,3),C= c(NA,NA,NA,NA), 
D=rep("DW 3*",4))
```

For loop, checking for which rows are NA, and selecting that column name to then be used for replacement:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  df2[i,colnames(df2)[which(is.na(df2[i,]))][1]]=3
  }
```